# What is a good way to archive webpages in a form that that is "future proof" against browser software updates?

Tags: updates, firefox, websites

I want to be able to store webpages, from various websites of interest, long term, for later reference. How do browser software updates affect me being able to do this? Is there some form they can be stored in which is not affected by software changes?

Also, is there a way to save webpages so that they can be loaded by any particular browser software (Firefox, Chrome, Explorer etc.)?

Comment: Does this reference help? https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-download-a-web-page-or-article-to-read-offline

Comment: It is a bit unreasonable to expect a change proof solution, without knowing what the changes are, and across multiple browsers.

Comment: @mikewhatever Unrealistic perhaps but not unreasonable. It wouldn't exactly be a technological miracle for software to be written so that it is fully backward compatible. I see no reason why e.g. MS Word could not be updated and retain the ability to read a Word document made on Word 1.0.

Comment: @User24601 I already know how to basically save webpages. I'm interested to know if it is possible to keep pages readable with updates in browser software and also across different browsers. However, I wonder if saving it as a HTML file could achieve this, rather than as "webpage complete"? Or saving only the text version at least, though this would exclude images?

Comment: Backward compatible, yes, but what you want is, apparently forward compatible, or future proof. It is not impossible to write a program, ten years down the road, to support some abandoned formats. In fact, it is both reasonable and realistic. However, that's not what you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Pocket Button at the end of the Firefox address bar to save any article, video or page from Firefox. Then you can view the saved pages from any of your devices that have Firefox installed. The Pocket listen feature lets you listen to your articles.

[image]

If you want to archive the current state of a webpage you can save it at [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/). There isn't any requirement to sign up for the Wayback Machine website in order to save webpages.